# How to modify PathMatch to AntPathMatcher during springboot operation through reflection

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-test

How to modify PathMatch to AntPathMatcher during springboot operation through reflection. I don't want to modify it through the spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy property in the application.properties configuration file, I want to modify it during runtime through reflection